# Measure average network traffic in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

I'd like to measure the average network traffic (up & down) over a predefined interval (say, 300 seconds) and make a decision based on the traffic value.

When shell scripting, one can easily use vnstat. Is there way I could do this in Python 3?

I know I could use `os.subprocess` for this, but `os.subprocess` is always the last resort option.

Comment: You could look at `psutil` which offers functions for getting network statistics.

Comment: For example, see [`net_io_counters`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.net_io_counters). A little linked scripted in the docs [does pretty much what you're looking for.](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/scripts/nettop.py#L94)

Comment: You can parse `/proc/net/dev`.